# awk / sed: find string and return its previous index

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to get with awk an index based in a query.

If a command (pacmd list-sink-inputs) returns this list of audios being played:

> ```
> 2 sink input(s) available.
>
> index: 19
>     driver: <protocol-native.c>
>     flags: START_CORKED
>     state: RUNNING
>             ...   
>             (undetermined number of lines) 
>             ...  
>     sink: 0 <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo>
>     volume: front-left: 45875 /  70% / -9.29 dB,   front-right: 45875 /  70% / -9.29 dB
>             balance 0.00
>     module: 8
>     client: 713 
>     properties:
>             application.icon_name = "chromium-browser"
>             application.language = "C"    
>             ...   
>             (undetermined number of lines) 
>             ...   
> index: 20
>     driver: <sound-file-stream.c>
>     flags:
>     state: RUNNING
>     sink: 0 <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo>
>     volume: front-left: 9830 /  15% / -49.44 dB,   front-right: 9830 /  15% / -49.44 dB
>             balance 0.00
>     muted: no
>     resample method: speex-float-1
>     properties:
>             media.name = "audio.wav"
>             media.filename = "/usr/local/sounds/audio.wav"
>             media.format = "WAV (Microsoft)"
>             module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-name:audio.wav"
> ```

I know how to get each index, with:
*pacmd list-sink-inputs | awk '$1 == "index:" {print $2}'*

Response:

> ```
> 19
> 20
> ```

But what I need are **only the indexes of the audios played in "chromium-browser".**

Wanted response:

> ```
> 19
> ```

Is it possible with awk or sed? What would be the query?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you please do add method by which you want to get output? Also please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: This is `pactl list-sinks` output. Just grep for `index:` or `application.icon_name` strings, then remove the newline in front `application` and then `grep` again.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry if I was unclear. I modified the question to be more specific in what I tried and what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe your command into the following GNU `sed` command :

```
sed -En '/^\s*index:/h;/application\.icon_name = "chromium-browser"/{x;s/index: //;p;q}'
```

This will store every index line `sed` encounters into its hold buffer, then when it reaches the "chromium-browser" line it swaps the content of the hold buffer, extract the index from the line, prints it then exits.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/Z6BPiZ#stdout).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation.
I confirm it works, so I'm going to mark it as solved.

I'm sorry if I in the first hour I didn't ask better the question, I'll be glad if the downvoters point me what can I improve, or if they consider it correct now, undo the downvote.

Thank you again to everbody.

Comment: Basic linux/bash questions will be better received and get answers as good if not better if you post them on the [Unix&Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than on StackOverflow. I don't think there was much room to improve your question